# Recreating range function, can not get the decrementing list

Tags: python, function, range

I am working on a project were I need to essentially recreate the `range` function in Python. The assignment dictates:

> Define and test a function `myRange`. This function should behave like Python’s standard `range` function, with the required and optional arguments, but it should return a list. Do not use the `range` function in your implementation!

I think I am just about there. Here is my code so far:

```
numList = []
def myRange(start, stop=None, step=None):
    if stop == None and step == None:
        start, stop, step = 0, start, 1
        while step <= stop:
            numList.append(step-1)
            step+=1            
    elif start < stop and step == None:
        start, stop, step = start, stop, start
        while step < stop:
            numList.append(step)
            step+=1

    elif start > stop and step == None:
        start, stop, step = start, stop, start
        while start >= stop:
            numList.append(step)
            step -= 1
            
    else:
        start, stop, step = start, stop, step
        while start < stop:
            numList.append(start)
            start+=step
    return numList


    
print(myRange(90,80))
```

I am currently trying to print a decrementing list from 90 to 80. Where I am stuck is here:

```
 elif start > stop and step == None:
            start, stop, step = start, stop, start
            while start >= stop:
                numList.append(step)
                step -= 1
```

This should work, that is, `start` is greater then `stop`.

And when there is no `step` indicated, then it should append the value of `step` (assigned to the value of `start`), and then it should do minus one from what `step` is set to, and add the next value to `numList`.

Why isn't this working that way?

Comment: Not your question, but `range` does not return a list (in Python 3), and if you do `range(90, 80)`, you'll get an empty range. Do you *really* need to mimic `range`, or are there different rules to this challenge?

Comment: As to your problem, in the loop `while start >= stop:` you never change anything that affects that condition, so it will loop for ever. This should be very easy to detect when running your code with a debugger though.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance on the conditions. I will edit them to avoid infinite loops. The assignment is having use make our own range function that returns a list. Assignment dictates: Define and test a function myRange. This function should behave like Python’s standard range function, with the required and optional arguments, but it should return a list. Do not use the range function in your implementation!

Comment: i do need some way of making a list that decrements

Comment: But for decrementing you must provide the step argument, that's how it works with the native function.

Comment: I added the information you provided in comments (the assignment's description) to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues:

- You write you want to get a decrementing list with `myRange(90,80)`, but that is not the expected output for that call. The native function `range(90,80)` will return an empty range, because the step is by default 1. You should not decide to step by -1 just because `start > stop`. That is not how it should work. The *only* way to get a negative step, is by providing it as argument.
- The following loop is problematic:

  ```
  while start >= stop:
      numList.append(step)
      step -= 1
  ```

  because the condition `start >= stop` will always be true, no matter how many times you do `step -= 1`. That doesn't influence the loop condition. So eventually the process will throw an exception -- when it is out of memory because of the millions of calls to `numList.append`.
- When the function is called with a *negative* step, then the last block will be executed, but the `while` condition is wrong. In case the step is negative, it should be `while start > stop`. Because of this, `myRange(2, 0, -1)` will return an empty list, but it should return `[2, 1]`.
- `numList` should not be a global name. As you have it now, a second call of `myRange` will not reset that list, and just extend it further. Also it is problematic that every call to `myRange` will return the *same* single list object. You'll always only have one list. This is wrong. Every call to `myRange` should return a distinct list, not related to what a previous call returned. So `numList` should be a *local* name.
- The native `range` will raise an exception when the third argument is 0. You should maybe implement that too.
- The function declaration should not have `None` as default for `step`, as really the default is 1.
- You have different ways of determining the value to append. Sometimes `step-1`, sometimes `step`, sometimes `start`. This should better be harmonised. If there is a value to put in the list, the first one will *always* be the value of `start` (taking into account that if only one argument was provided, `start` is to be 0). So it makes sense to always use `start` in the `append` call, and have `start += step` in the loop.

Here is a correction:

```
# The default for step is 1, not None
def myRange(start, stop=None, step=1):
    # Deal with the case where only one argument is provided:
    if stop is None:
        # In that case it should be taken as the value for stop
        start, stop = 0, start
    # Treat the invalid value for step
    if step == 0:
        raise ValueError("myRange step cannot be 0")
    result = []   # A local name!
    if step > 0:  # The loop condition depends on the sign of the step
        while start < stop:
            result.append(start)
            start += step
    else:
        while start > stop:
            result.append(start)
            start += step
    return result
```